# Как правильно запустить hashkill?

Tags: пароль, linux

Знающие люди, помогите разобраться с данной утилитой, не смог разобраться, как запустить! Создал файлик с хешем который хочу расшифровать, ввожу команды, что нашел в гугле, но так и не могу запустить(( У данной утилиты есть 3 вида перебора: по словарю, гибридный, брутфорс! Буду очень благодарен, если будут подробно описаны все методы перебора (в особенности больше всего интересует брутфорс).

Answer (score 1):

У этой утилиты есть мануал. Согласно нему прямой перебор делается, например, так

```
hashkill -b[start:end:predefined_set:additional_set] -f hashes.txt
```

где

- start - минимальное число генерируемых перестановок
- end - максимальное число генерируемых перестановок
- predefined_set - основной набор символов (ascii и тд.)
- additional_set - дополнительный набор символов

Пример

```
hashkill -b1:4:num:abc -f hashlist.txt
```